# XCode 7 UI Testing: Dismissal of system-generated UIAlertController does not work

Tags: xcode7, uialertcontroller, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I have a UI test which involves the dismissal of a system-generated `UIAlertController`. This alert asks the user for the permission to access the device's calendar. The objective of the test is the behaviour after a tap on the `OK` button:

```
1 let app = XCUIApplication()
...
// this code was basically generated by the recording feature of XCode 7 
2 app.alerts.elementBoundByIndex(0).collectionViews.buttons["OK"].tap()
```

Now, instead of clicking the `OK` button, line 2 makes the simulator tap onto the first button which happens to be the `Cancel` button...

Additionally, I found out that the testing framework does not accurately recognize the appearing alert. So if I check the current count of alerts I always get 0:

```
// ...tap...
let count = app.alerts.count // == 0
```

This also happens if I use an `NSPredicate` for the condition and wait for several seconds.

Is it possible that UI tests do not work reliably with system-generated alerts? I am using XCode 7.0.1.

Comment: Interacting with system alerts via UI Testing is a [known bug/issue](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4979891669827584).

Comment: OMG! The XCode 7 bug detection journey seems to be a neverending story...

Comment: Not anymore, woot! Check out [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33700623/384110). :-)

Answer (score 8):

Xcode 7.1 has finally fixed the issue with system alerts. There are, however, two small gotchas.

First, you need to set up a "UI Interuption Handler" before presenting the alert. This is our way of telling the framework how to handle an alert when it appears.

Second, after presenting the alert you must interact with the interface. Simply tapping the app works just fine, but is required.

```
addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("Location Dialog") { (alert) -> Bool in
    alert.buttons["Allow"].tap()
    return true
}

app.buttons["Request Location"].tap()
app.tap() // need to interact with the app for the handler to fire
```

The "Location Dialog" is just a string to help the developer identify which handler was accessed, it is not specific to the type of alert. I believe that returning `true` from the handler marks it as "complete", which means it won't be called again.

Comment: Have you tried to dismissed several different alert in the row? I am trying to figure it out. However, it's more complicated than just registering multiple Interrupt Monitor (in reverse order)

Comment: Joe, thanks for sharing this. What about successive alerts right at launch? I have one asking for location, and then right after that for push notifications. With your approach I am able to dismiss the first one fine, but the second one doesn't fire `addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription` again. Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend `app.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVector(dx: 200, dy: 1)).tap()` instead of `app.tap()`, because it can click on something you're not expecting, as in my case, and break further test flow.

Comment: @VladimirTolstikov +1 this literally just happened to me, good call

Comment: I'd put that "second part" about the tap needed in bold or first.

Comment: I've run into an issue where the Interruption Monitor does not fire off on a System Dialog. Instead the magic `app.tap()` that you mentioned to interact with the app is the thing that is actually doing the press to Continue. Because `app.tap()` cannot guarantee that it won't press Cancel either.

Comment: Actually what I've noticed is when you reset the simulator and run the UI test, it does not trigger the monitor _at all_. Can anyone confirm that? Xcode 9, iPhone 8 iOS 11 simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to dismiss access prompt for contacts like this:

```
let alert = app.alerts["\u{201c}******\u{201d} Would Like to Access Your Contacts"].collectionViews.buttons["OK"]
if alert.exists
{
    alert.tap()
}
```

Replace asterisks with your app's name. It might work the same for calendar.

This is what I ended up using to get the prompt to appear and then allow access to Contacts:

```
func allowAccessToContacts(textFieldsName: String)
{
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    let textField = app.textFields[textFieldsName]
    textField.tap()
    textField.typeText("aaa")

    let alert = app.alerts["\u{201c}******\u{201d} Would Like to Access Your Contacts"].collectionViews.buttons["OK"]
    if alert.exists
    {
        alert.tap()
    }
    textField.typeText("\u{8}\u{8}\u{8}")
}
```