# iOS UITesting How to Dismiss Popover (iPad Popover NOT Alert Style)

Tags: ios, swift, testing

I have a pretty complicated app with a lot of views and popovers for fast picking entries.

I'm not able to dismiss a popover. I tried a lot like:

- Hitting coordinates in the window
- app.otherElements["PopoverDismissRegion"] Hitting elements behind the
- popover (which are not hittable at all)

When I record the it in XCode I get:
app.otherElements["PopoverDismissRegion"]

Which makes no sense to me.

Hope someone can help.

Thx

**Infos**: *iOS 10.2,Xcode 8.2.1, 
iPad Air 2 (Device and Simulator, same results)*

Comment: your ques is not clear, what you actually want to do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode 7 UI Testing: Dismissal of system-generated UIAlertController does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33124179/xcode-7-ui-testing-dismissal-of-system-generated-uialertcontroller-does-not-wor)

Comment: @vaibhav: What is not clear? I have an iPad style popover. I try to dismiss that.

Comment: @Elist the Popover has no button so no, it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT*

Found a better solution [here](http://www.matrixprojects.net/p/whats-new-with-ui-testing-in-ios10/):

```
XCUIApplication().otherElements["PopoverDismissRegion"].tap()
```

Original  solution:

Try this:

```
XCUIApplication().windows.element(boundBy: 0).tap()
```

Which taps the window and dismisses the currently active popover.

Comment: I tried this before, take a look on my second bullet. This was also suggested a lot, but it didn't worked for me. It probably works of an alert controller, but not for a table view which is presented as a popover from a nav bar item.

Answer (score 1):

Everything was working for me on iPhone simulators by just doing:

```
app.swipeDown(velocity: .fast)
```

I started to have problems when I wanted the same test to run on iPad simulators. The gesture was being applied but it was not big enough to dismiss the view. I tried different things like:

```
XCUIApplication().windows.element(boundBy: 0).tap()
```

or

```
app.otherElements["PopoverDismissRegion"].tap()
```

but none of the work. The view was still not being dismissed.

Doing more testing on it I found that the view will actually be dismissed sending the `swipeDown` gesture if iPad Simulator is on landscape. So... I was able to solve the problem like this:

```
// If iPad, put the simulator on landscape mode
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad { 
    XCUIDevice.shared.orientation = .landscapeLeft
}

// Perform the swipe
app.swipeDown(velocity: .fast)

// Restore device portrait mode
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad { 
    XCUIDevice.shared.orientation = .portrait
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do I have achieved this? This way below:

1. Find a starting coordinates origin x and origin y of the poped up
   view, ref:
   [How to tap on a specific point using Xcode UITests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285090/how-to-tap-on-a-specific-point-using-xcode-uitests/60494349#60494349)
2. Then do the minus on coordinates to tap outside the frame of poped up view, Then do the tap action.

It will dismiss the Pop up , and tests will pass.