# How can I disable the "Join Wi-Fi network" alert message in Swift?

Tags: ios, alert, nehotspothelper

I'm making an App that connects to a hostpot, but whenever I press the button to connect, an alert message appears:

> "WiFi-Conenct" Wants to join Wi-Fi Network "Name of a network"?

[image: screenshot of the alert]

How can I disable it, or set join?

Answer (score 4):

**You cannot disable this prompt.**

It was meant to be there to enforce security and to give users the ultimate decision whether they want to join to a particular network.

Comment: So how can I set Join via Swift.

Comment: Because Im doing a Automation in this app, and there is no human to press this button.

Comment: @MatheusMarques [Take a look at this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33124179/3151675)

Comment: That didn't solve my problem, this solution its for xcode 7.1, and I'm using xcode 9.1

Comment: @TamásSengel is there any official link where this privacy policy has been described?

Comment: Not that I know of @BiswajitKarmakar

Comment: @MatheusMarques https://medium.com/tauk-blog/handling-alert-interruptions-in-ios-ui-tests-f3b6d059940f